# execute function when a certain fragment appears in reveal.js

Tags: javascript, charts, reveal.js

Is it possible to call a function, when a certain fragment in a section appears?

I use `Chart.js` and I want to draw a certain chart when the fragment css class changes to visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fragment events](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/tree/bac187f3a0f7e8f92d33ca0258fe2e96553d2930#fragment-events) should allow you to do this. I use slide states to do the same thing, only for slides.